# Access Graph APIs with MessengerPageScopedID

Tags: facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-messenger

Lately, I have been testing the messenger platform.
So far everything works great but I wanted to get a little more infos about the user than just the basic profile infos.
When a user talks to you via Messenger you get a specific userId which, from what I understood, is not only page-scoped but also messenger-scoped.
In the [messenger documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/implementation#user_profile_api), there is an example with a call to the user profile API like this:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<USER_ID>?fields=first_name,last_name,profile_pic,locale,timezone,gender&amp;access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

However, even though my app has the user_events permission, I cannot access the corresponding graph api node.

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/<USER_ID>/events?fields=id,name&amp;access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

returns an error like this one:

```
{
    message: '(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (events) on node type (MessengerPageScopedID)',
    type: 'OAuthException',
    code: 100,
    fbtrace_id: 'E+ramLeapT5'
}
```

I don't use the graph-api often, could it be due to the fact that my page is still in development and doesn't have the permission in the "approved items" category?
Is there a way to link the messenger-scoped id to a simpler page-scoped or app-scoped id that I could use to make this kind of calls? Maybe with a custom entry point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access anything else but public_profile fields using this special token. Access to the user events endpoint requires user_events permission and since users do not need to login to your app to message you page, there's no way to retrieve permissions to access anything besides the user's public_profile fields.

Comment: Is there any way to check if this messenger user is the same facebook user who has already auth'd my app elsewhere?

Comment: It's a bit roundabout, but you can retrieve the Message object from the Graph API, which has the actual Facebook user id, and then retrieve the Facebook User object using that (also using the Graph API). You might not want to rely on this though, I think that there's a reason why they put in place page scoped ids.